# How to Handle "Cannot run with sound null safety" error with Visual Studio AppCenter in Flutter APK Build

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-app-center, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to add AppCenter to my application but I get build error:

> Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following
> dependencies don't support null safety:
>
> - package:appcenter
> - package:appcenter_analytics
> - package:appcenter_crashes
>
> For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I added auto-generated code from AppCenter to my ->app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    def appCenterSdkVersion = '4.3.1'
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spending some hours in pain, I found my solution and post it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69996401/appcenter-with-flutter-ios-and-android)

We should not import appcenter, appcenter_analytics appcenter_crashespackage in main.dart (also not import them into pubspec.yaml)
What we should do is, override "onCreate" method in MainActivity.java and implement appcenter there.
You can find more details in my answer.