# AppCenter with Flutter (IOS and Android)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, visual-studio-app-center

Right now we are developing 2 flutter projects, both is running work on Android and IOS. No problems there (yey)
The problem I'm having is, I cannot find a way to implement AppCenter into my project.
The guide on the official website is actually very straight-forward but it does not working, gives null-safety error:
Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies don't support null safety:
package:appcenter
package:appcenter_analytics
package:appcenter_crashes

I walked around with --no-sound-null-safety arg but that did not helped with IOS. Cant even "run" the project. [My Question About It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69988551/how-to-handle-cannot-run-with-sound-null-safety-error-with-visual-studio-appce/69988829#69988829)

Secondly I tried [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appcenter_bundle) but no matter how I proceed, I could not manage to make it work both for IOS and Android. Last error I was having was *"Unsupported Android Plugin version: 7.0.0."* (the instruction was telling me to follow the settings in the example project of the plugin in GitHub)
so, I'm at a dead end here..

Can anyone suggest a proper way for me to follow for AppCenter?

Why AppCenter you may ask? Because firebase is only for "test" distribution and I really need to use AppCenter's public publish service.

Comment: Please read tag descriptors before using the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after spending some hours in pain, I found the solution.
So, here's how:

android\app\src\main\java\com\arkitek\flutter\arkitek_app_internal\MainActivity.java

```
    package com.arkitek.flutter.arkitek_app_internal;
    import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
    import com.microsoft.appcenter.AppCenter;
    import com.microsoft.appcenter.analytics.Analytics;
    import com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.Crashes;
    import com.microsoft.appcenter.distribute.Distribute;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    
    public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    
    @Override
    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    AppCenter.start(getApplication(), "OUR SECRET KEY", Distribute.class);
    
    AppCenter.setEnabled(true);
    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
}}
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"/>
```

app/build.grade:

```
dependencies {

    def appCenterSdkVersion = '4.2.0'

    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}"

    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}"

    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-distribute:${appCenterSdkVersion}"

}
```

Also,

To let AppCenter know that, you are releasing an update, you should update your versionCode's in 3 files:

android\app\build.gradle

```
..
Android {

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.arkitek.flutter.arkitek_app_internal"
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 30
versionCode 9
versionName "1.0.19"
}
```

pubspec.yaml ->

```
version: 1.0.19+1
```

and android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="9"
android:versionName="1.0.19"
package="com.arkitek.flutter.arkitek_app_internal">
```

And that was it. This is how I solved my issues.

Comment: This was very helpful. There is no official documentation which is suggesting this to configure like this on Flutter.